# I can't access my Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have Firebase Crashlytics set up correctly on my application. But I have been unable to access my Crashlytics dashboard on Firebase.

It keeps taking me to this page to this page up fabric which I have been unable to. Is there a way around this.

[image: Page Link]

Comment: How do you know you have it set up correctly? What happens if you check "already has Crashlytics installed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here - hopefully this helps anyone who might run into something like this in the future. More clarification has been added to this particular screen since this question's creation as well.

One reason why this can happen is some sort of misstep in the migration process. If you have a Fabric app and are attempting to migrate to Firebase Crashlytics, you should complete the [clickthrough migration](https://fabric.io/firebase_migration) and then you should be able to entirely skip seeing these options once that's complete. No other code changes are required. You will also be linked to the clickthrough migration if you choose option 1 on step 1 of the above view.

Other than that, ensure that you're installing Crashlytics correctly via [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started). You can also click "Test your Implementation" at the bottom of that page to see how you can enable Crashlytics debug logging (to verify in your Xcode logs if Crashlytics is communicating with the server) and perform a test crash.